# Can you take multiple items in list and combine them and add "x(amount)" at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My list has different number of items, can I combine them?

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item1', 'item2 x25', 'item3', 'item2 x5']
```

I'm looking to combine the `list1` and output `desired_list`

```
desired_list = ['item1 x2', 'item2 x30', 'item3']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DaniMesejo other than making a tree of if statements for every possible number no, I don't really know what else to try

Comment: is that counter actually a part of the string? why don't you use some key-value datatype as dictionary, where you could use items as keys and number of items as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, it doesn't looked like you've tried a lot, so I'll just try to head you off in the right direction.

You can use .split() in the form of:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    list1[i] = item.split()
```

To get something that looks like:

```
list1 = [['item1'], ['item1'], ['item2', 'x25'], ['item3'], ['item2', 'x30']]
```

This tells you that if you have no item in the second element of a list, it has a quantity of 1 and for the rest of them you can find the quantity after the x. You can do something like this to change it again.

```
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    if len(item) == 1:
        item.append(1)
    else:
        list1[i][1] = item[1][1:]
```

and that turns the list into:
`list1 = [['item1', 1], ['item1', 1], ['item2', '25'], ['item3', 1], ['item2', '5']]`

Where you have the first element of each one telling which item and the second telling it's quantity. Then you can find like-items and add together their qualities with something like

```
items = {}
for item in list1:
    if item[0] not in items.keys():
else:
    items[item[0]] += int(item[1])
```

Then `list1 = list(items.items())` turns it back into a list which provides the output [('item1', 2), ('item2', 30), ('item3', 1)] you desired. Ofcourse if you want it in the "item1 x2" format you can do:

```
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    list1[i] = " x".join(list1)
```

Which would change it all back into strings and the list would look like `list1 = ["item1 x2", "item2 x30", "item3 x1"]`